# How to send json messages between Node.js services inside a docker compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, docker-compose

Let's say I have two Node.js services running inside a docker compose. Service A listens to port 4000 and service B listens to port 5000. How can I send a json message from service A to B (and vice versa) (by using Express)?

Comment: There are at least 1000 possible ways to do this. It dependes on what you like the most. redis, rabbitmq, master/slave messaging, tcp broadcast, websocket broadcasts, udp multicast, udp anycast. And so...

Comment: Thank you for these recommendations. Is there a way using Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple docker-compose file, the two services can access each other using their service name. This is defined by the top level key underneath `services:`. In this simple example, service `one` could talk to service `two` by simply adressing it as `http://two:5000`. The other direction works the same using `http://one:4000` assuming the processes internally listen on those port numbers. Both containers could also listen on the same port internally as they have different network interfaces. Make sure to not get confused with the port mappings to your localhost (4444 and 5555) here.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  one:
    image: yourname/yourimage-one
    ports:
      - "4444:4000"
  two:
    image: yourname/yourimage-two
    ports:
      - "5555:5000"
```

For more advanced setups, please refer to the [docker-compose docs on networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

I assume you are talking about REST APIs using JSON as data format. There are many ways to do this. Express itself is used for building the server side, not the client. You can use the standard APIs like [shown in the nodejs docs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) or one of several third party libraries to perform requests. [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for example is a pretty popular library for http requests. See [one example for axios in the node docs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/make-an-http-post-request-using-nodejs), too.

In most cases it's not a good idea to have circular connections using http requests in both directions. Maybe one of the two can act as the producing service and the other one is more like the consuming one?

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. My scenario is the following: Service A received a message from a client like requesting user information. Since service B  is responsible for user entities, Service A request B for the data by sending an id. Service B receives the id and sends back the requested data to A. After this, A sends the user data to the client. So there has to be a cycle between A and B. I need A to send a json with the id to url:port_from_B and B to send the user data as json back to url:port_from_A. Axios looks like the right library. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. This is a simple request-response from service A to service B which is totally fine. I was referring to a scenario where in addition to that, service B would also actively request against service A. One way is fine and pretty common.